# Easy Facebook Android

Tags: android, windows, facebook

I have problem with the integration of [EasyFacebook](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/) in my application but only when using 
`Windows 8`

. When I am building the app from `Mac` and `Windows 7` the Share on facebook works perfectly but when I am building the app from my Windows 8 on Share click `EasyFacebook` throws `nullpointerexception`. I got all of the Key Hashes on my Facebook application and building the exact same code on all of the platforms works except on `Windows 8`.

Here is the stacktrace of the problem.

```
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:50)
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.encodeUrl(Util.java:87)
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:147)
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.GraphApi.getUserCall(GraphApi.java:2064)
05-08 13:15:03.533: W/System.err(28487):    at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.GraphApi.getMyAccountInfo(GraphApi.java:2045)
```

Is anyone else occurring any problems with Eclipse and Windows 8?